# How do I perform a simple regular expression match in bash?

Tags: regex, bash

I'm trying to match the number that's in the beginning of a string

> 452MATCHME

With this simple regex

```
/^\d*/
```

And I want this result, saved in a variable

> 452

But I can't find a way to get the result of the operation. I've read [this tutorial](http://www.linuxjournal.com/content/bash-regular-expressions), but it describes an array `BASH_REMATCH` where all match results of `=~` operations are stored. That array doesn't exist in my case though, for some reason. I'm using bash version 4.2.10(1).

The only other option I can think of is `grep`, but that can only output which lines matched the regex, as far as I know.

How can I achieve my result?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So it seems the issue was that BASH regex doesn't support `\d`. Use `[0-9]` instead.

Answer (score 4):

```
var=452MATCHME
echo ${var%%[^0-9]*}
```

This will delete from the first non-digit to the end.

Bash parameter is sufficient for most cases so I'd suggest you get familiar with it. Here is the link for bash pattern:
http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Pattern-Matching

Answer (score 4):

this will work:

```
if [[ "452MATCHME" =~ ^([0-9]+).* ]]
then 
    echo ${BASH_REMATCH[1]};
fi
```

P.S: I'm using bash 3.0 version, it's just you regex that isn't well formed.

Comment: In bash 4, the pattern must NOT be quoted: `[[ "452MATCHME" =~ ^[0-9]+ ]] && echo ${BASH_REMATCH[0]}`